# How to rectify 'Index was outside the bounds of the array (Microsoft.sqlserver.Express.smo)' in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I am using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio Express.

I installed this few days back. when i try to create a new database or new table, I am getting the below error message:

> Cannot show requested dialog.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Cannot show requested dialog. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.SqlMgmt)
>
> Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

I tried installing some service packs. But nothing worked.

Can you please help me out of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *SQL Server Management Studio Express 2012* I have seen useless error messages when creating databases in SSMS when either a) you are connecting to an ancient version of SQL Server or b) you do not have the appropriate permissions. E.g. "BUILTIN\Administrators" is granted `sysadmin` and you are not running SSMS "As Administrator"

Comment: @ta.spoet.is . Can you please explain on this. Is there any methods to rectify this

Comment: a) don't connect to an ancient version of SQL Server b) right click SSMS and choose "Run as administrator"

Comment: @ta.speot.is . I tried.still struck up with the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the interface of the Management Studio to create a database or a table then try writing the query by clicking New Query on the top left corner of the management studio.

for creating a new database use :

```
   CREATE DATABASE database_name
```

to use the database after creating it :

```
   USE database_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i dont want to create database by querying manually. I need to create by using the inbuild tools.